# TRMM Values Conversion From Float to Integer in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, remote-sensing

In the below code TRMM product values converted from float to integer type in Google Earth Engine. However after the conversion TRMM product just shows 0 and 1. How can I can do conversion without this error?

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/76c3540de4e0fe14d022dc1bf789d586

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);

var start = '2018-01-01';
var end = '2019-01-01';

var precipitation = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/PERSIANN-CDR")
.filterDate(start, end)
.filterBounds(table)
.select('precipitation').mean().toInt16()
.clip(table)
.rename('precipitation');

print('precipitation',precipitation);

Map.addLayer(precipitation,{
  palette: ['blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
},'precipitation',false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.toInt16()` does not automatically scale the data to fit, so your values are being rounded to integers. You have to scale the data to suit your needs.

For example, it looks like 0 to 3 is a typical range of your data. So, you can write `.multiply(32767 / 3).toInt16()` to get a reasonable result. (32767 is the highest possible value of a 16-bit signed integer.)

```js
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);

var precipitation = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/PERSIANN-CDR")
  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2019-01-01')
  .filterBounds(table)
  .select('precipitation')
  .mean()
  .multiply(32767 / 3)
  .toInt16()
  .clip(table);

Map.addLayer(precipitation, {
  palette: ['blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'],
}, 'precipitation', true);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/05846c48bb38f59ff3c654533b1015db

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Excellent and how can I return converted integer to the primary float value?

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhrari `.toFloat().divide(3 / 32767)`, but if you want that, then it would be better to not convert to integer at all.